# Javascript iframe speed issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, iframe

So I am working on this page which is an online catalog. You enter something in the search bar and it loads the results. In the results you canclick on the image you would like to see, then the a large image and some details appear in an iframe. My problem is when there is a lot of search results the iframe is painfully slow to load and also close, but when only a few items are displayed it runs rather quickly. Does anyone have an idea why?

```
<script>
//this affect the content that is loaded in the iframe when image is clicked
$( document ).load( "pageinit", "#page1", function() {    
    $(".popupInfoLink").on("click", function(){
        var url = $(this).data("popupurl");
        $( "#popupInfo iframe" ).attr("src", url);

    });    

//this clears the frame when you navigate away

    $("#popupInfo").on("popupafterclose", function(){
        $( "#popupInfo iframe" ).attr("src", '');
    });

});
```

Below is the script affecting the iframe and the thumbnail that runs the script.

```
<div>
<a class="popupInfoLink" href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-popupurl="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]"><img src= "/[THUMBNAIL]" style="max-height:300px; min-height:150px;" alt="pot" border="0" />
</a>
</div>


<div data-role="popup" id="popupInfo" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
    <iframe src="about:blank" width="100%" height="200px" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

My question is why would the speed of the iframe loading dramatically slower when more items show up in the search results opposed to only a few items if it is only loading one iframe in both scenarios?

Comment: The bottleneck is on your server side. the ASP is taking a bit to return the results. You could make this a better user experience by adding a loader (spinner) in the iframe, when the content is retrieved from the server (via your search) it replaces the spinner.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about doing that, adding some little animated gif. Another answer could be to use ajax instead of iframes, what do you guys think? @jamesemanon

Answer (score 0):

Think about thumbnails. If you can dramatically reduce the size of the pictures being loaded you can dramatically reduce load time. Thumbnails can be dynamically generated server side.

Comment: Ajax is great for dynamic loading but I am unsure of any benefit gained by using it over iframes. Ajax will definitely be cooler. But iframes get the job done quickly(code wise).

Comment: also what are you pulling the pictures from?